# Spring ApplicationContext Bean Scope

Tags: java, spring

When you create a Service bean or Dao bean in your Spring applicationContext.xml file, what is the scope of those beans?

Will every person who accesses the web application use the same instance of the bean, or is the bean instantiated for each user's session?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default a bean created in Spring is of scope **singleton**, so yes each person will access the same instance in those cases.  The alternative is to specify the scope as **prototype**.

More info on this here, sections 3.4.1 and 3.4.2:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype

Comment: Wow! It's right there in the documentation. I don't know how I missed it, but thank you VERY much for pointing me to it.

Answer (score -2):

By default a bean created in Spring is of scope singleton. However, if you use Spring DispatcherServlet and DispatcherPortlet, a bean scope is requested.