# Does an Object in Spring created every time we write getBean()?

Tags: spring, object, inversion-of-control

I have read that whenever we do getBean() in spring, it returns desired object.
So does it mean, if i write call getBean() 1000 times, thousand object will be created ?? 
If yes, Than how Spring manages these objects ?
if No, Please explain how Spring works with respect to object creation ?
Is there something Object pool kind of concept ?
Please clarify my doubts. I am new to spring and is very confused whether spring framework is created to make our task easy or to make things more complicated.
Spring seems to be a web of XMLs :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring ApplicationContext Bean Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209874/spring-applicationcontext-bean-scope)

Answer (score 5):

From the [Spring Framework documentation on singleton bean factory scope](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-singleton):

> ### The singleton scope
>
> Only one shared instance of a singleton bean is managed, and all
> requests for beans with an id or ids matching that bean definition
> result in that one specific bean instance being returned by the Spring
> container.
>
> To put it another way, when you define a bean definition and it is
> scoped as a singleton, the Spring IoC container creates exactly one
> instance of the object defined by that bean definition. This single
> instance is stored in a cache of such singleton beans, and all
> subsequent requests and references for that named bean return the
> cached object.

To sum it up, no, Spring will create only a single instance of each bean in a bean factory unless you change the default scope of **singleton** to some other bean scope.

[Other bean scopes](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes) include:

> ### Bean scopes
>
> **singleton**
>
> (Default) Scopes a single bean definition to a
> single object instance per Spring IoC
> container.
>
> **prototype**
>
> Scopes a single bean
> definition to any number of object instances.
>
> **request**
>
> Scopes a single bean definition to the
> lifecycle of a single HTTP request; that is, each HTTP request has its
> own instance of a bean created off the back of a single bean
> definition. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring
> ApplicationContext.
>
> **session**
>
> Scopes a single
> bean definition to the lifecycle of an HTTP Session. Only valid in the
> context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
>
> **global session**
>
> Scopes a single bean definition to the
> lifecycle of a global HTTP Session. Typically only valid when used in a portlet
> context. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring
> ApplicationContext.